# Which one is efficient , Make an ajax call to server or loop through the data array

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a array of data ,let us say var products =[]; products array will contains 10000 elements
Now i just want to find out all the products which is having name item1 .
In this case which one is efficient(in case of performace) making an ajax call to server to get the items with name item1, or Loop through products array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't recommend you to keep 10000 elements in browser.

You can do a simple test to see how much memory it will take. I'll explain it with Chrome browser.
Open blank page, hit F12 to open developer tools and go to 'Profiles' tab. Then simply click on the 'eye' icon on the bottom - you will see new memory snapshot on left. When you click its size will appear under its name. Next go to 'Console' tab and run this code:

```js
var products = {};
for (var i = 10000; i--; ) {
    products['name' + i] = {
        id             : i, 
        description    : (new Array(201)).join('x')
    };
}
```

Then return to the 'Profiles' tab and take second snapshot with 'eye' icon. When you compare their size you will see how much memory this simple objects took. In my case it is about 3MB and this are simple objects only with two fields: id and 200 chars of description. If you would have more complicated objects it would take much more. Of course it would be better if you would use objects similar to your to see how it would look like.

Second thing is that if you decide to use them in browser you have send all of them to it. So with simple objects like above even when you strip unnecessary whitespaces and single object will look like this:

```js
p['namex']={id:x,description:'200 chars here....'};
```

and it will take about 250 chars per one entry, so with 10 000 entries you will send about 250 x 10 000 = 2 500 000 chars which is approximately about 2.5MB. And you will send this to client on every page reload/refresh.

Third point: if you would like to do searching by name (as you wrote in your question) you can't use javascript object to this - objects with the same name overwrite predecessors. In this case you should rather use simple array. Moreover even if names would be different and you would like to search names which contains some string, e.g. you have this data

```js
products['item1']     = {/** some data */};
products['foo']       = {/** some data */};
products['item13']    = {/** some data */};
products['bar']       = {/** some data */};
products['xitem1']    = {/** some data */};
```

and you would like to find all products which contains word 'item' you should use array instead of object because iterating over array is faster than iterating on object with for .. in loop (moreover iterating on array in reverse order is also quite faster than in standard order).

When it comes to server side searching there is also a lot of things to consider - performance can depend on many factors like your backend technology (language, database) and also can be boosted by e.g. memcached or redis which should give you really good time of response, and I'm sure that this would be better than sending all data from database to client on each request and dealing with it in browser :)

Answer (score 0):

Test it, and measure and compare your results.

That said, are you more concerned with the performance of the client or the server?  (Please, consider both!)  The resources will be spent in one or the other.  However, the server will likely be able to do it more efficiently, especially if it involves a Select query against an index on a proper database, etc.

If you already need to have the entire products array within JavaScript on the client (though I wouldn't recommend it - only if required) - I'd just keep the search local to the client.

Another consideration is, will this be a one-time search, or will there likely be multiple searches against the same collection of products.  If multiple searches, this would be another vote for the client.

Finally, what are you searching for?  If just an exact String match on a product name, use a JavaScript Object as a HashMap instead, indexed by name - then you don't even need to loop through the entire array.  For example:

```
var products = {};
products["item1"] = {description: "...", ...};
products["item2"] = {description: "...", ...};
```

At this point, accessing `products["item1"]` is a constant-time (and fast) operation.  Such a JavaScript collection could also be used along-side your existing array of products, with minimal additional resources required - especially if the values of both the array and the map are pointing to the same objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would first wonder why you're sending an array of 10,000 elements down to the browser in the first place.  That can't be small to transfer and certainly can't be making for a fast page display or good load on your server.

That said, if you're going to put that array on the client anyway, then chances are pretty good that looking through it with javascript will be faster than a roundtrip to your server as long as you're efficient about it.  We can't know for sure just by guessing so you'd have to test it yourself to be sure.

If it were me, I probably wouldn't be putting such a large array on the client in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are in need of performance i would rather say :
1. use a class to hold the array and make methord for searching
2. use ajax to send key word and get the result in array in your page 
Note use caching to increase speed/performance .